# Which 8080 conditional jump instruction would the compiler generate for if (a !=b)?

Tags: assembly, intel-8080

Options:

1. jz
2. jnz
3. jc
4. jnc

I have the answer to this question but am struggling to understand exactly what it is asking. What does it mean and what would be a good way to brush up on this topic? Thanks.

Comment: I suppose `JNZ` (jump if Z flag is not set)

Comment: If you have the answer, then why don't you ask "why does the 8080 compiler generate this instruction for if(a != b)"?

Comment: Sorry for sounding blunt, but "a good way to brush up on this topic" is to actually *read* about it. There are plenty of references and resource about 8080 assembly if you just look a little.

Comment: Also, what instruction or set of instructions a "compiler" would generate depends quite a lot on the actual compiler. It also depends even more on what `a` and `b` are. If we don't know which compiler is used, or what `a` and `b` is, then we can't answer it.

Comment: The blunt answer would obviously be "JNZ" - The actual one "any of those"

Comment: Both `jz` and `jnz` are plausible, depending on the surrounding code and how the compiler operates. `jc` and `jnc` are unlikely, but still possible. As posed, it's just not a very good question. Demand better from your curriculum.

Comment: That question is invalid, you can't compare two values by single conditional jump instruction. The CPU would have to do first some arithmetic operation upon `a` and `b` to set some flags, then maybe one of the options would do the desired thing. And without giving away definition whether code following the jump is equal or non-equal case, it's impossible to answer it correctly even if the question would specify the `cmp a,b` is done ahead. If this question is from your lector, you should rather get some good book and study yourself, because I have some doubts...

Comment: Yes to say the curriculum is poor would be an understatement but I suppose that is what one would expect from a university ranked 50th in the country.

Answer (score 2):

I used mainly the x86 instruction set, but it seems the [8080 one](https://www.google.co.il/#q=intel+8080+instruction+set) is close enough, so the jump instructions are the same.

In x86 (or 8080), if your C code looks like this

```
if (a != b)
{
    code1
}
code2
```

the compiler will usually produce assembly code like this:

```
    cmp a, b
    jz label2

    code1

label2:

    code2
```

In pseudo-code

1. Compare `a` and `b`
2. If they were equal, go to 4 (skip `code1`)
3. `code1`
4. `code2`

---

An optimizing compiler can change your code layout (sometimes radically, so you will see neither `cmp` nor `jz`), but you cannot predict that, so the best you can do is assume there were no optimizations and rearrangements.